# Removing a menu from a wxPython MenuBar

Tags: python, wxpython, menubar

I have created a MenuBar and appended a number of Menu objects to it.

I now want to remove one of the menus, having only reference to the Menu object appended, and not knowing or caring about the positioning and labeling of the menus.

This seems like a trivial thing to do, but the API does not seem built to handle it; all methods are based on positions and labels.

There exists a MenuBar.Remove() method, but it takes the position as argument. No method takes a menu and returns its position.

The Detach() methods on Menus and MenuBars are undocumented and apparently do nothing.

I am sure this is a dumb question and that the solution is obvious, given that no one I could find have asked it before, but the solution eludes me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx

class wxTest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(150,100))
        self.button=wx.Button(self, -1, "Remove")
        self.init_menu() # 

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.remove_menu, self.button)
        self.sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sz.Add(self.button, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(self.sz)
        self.Show()

    def init_menu(self):
        self.mfile = wx.Menu()
        self.medit = wx.Menu()

        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menubar.Append(self.mfile, "File")
        self.menubar.Append(self.medit, "Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)

    def remove_menu(self,event):
        toRemove = self.mfile # Remove self.mfile
        posm = self.menubar.FindMenu(toRemove.GetTitle())
        # posm is the menu "position"
        if posm >= 0:
            self.menubar.Remove(posm)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=wxTest(None,"Test Menu")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
menuBarPos = self.menuBar.FindMenu('File')
if menuBarPos >= 0:
   self.menuBar.Remove(menuBarPos)
```

To remove the 'File' menu, if the menu doesn't exist, its position will be returned as -1